# How do I capture a value nested in an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, nested

I need to capture a variable from a value nested within an array, but I'm I can't figure out the syntax to specify the location of that value.

print_r($result_array) outputs the following array...

I want to capture "This value here!" in a variable.
$var = $result_array['order'] /// Then what???

```
Array
(
    [order] => Array
        (
            [line_items] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [catalog_object_id] => This value here!
                            [quantity] => 1
                        )

                )

            [fulfillments] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [state] => PROPOSED
                            [type] => PICKUP
                            [pickup_details] => Array
                                (
                                    [is_curbside_pickup] => 1
                                    [pickup_at] => 2020-05-20 05:09:02
                                    [recipient] => Array
                                        (
                                            [display_name] => John
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: normal array access e.g if you want `catalog_object_id`, then do this  `echo $result_array['order']['line_items'][0]['catalog_object_id'];`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You are already on the right way. You can access the value with `$result_array['order']['line_items'][0]['catalog_object_id']`. Note that you have a multidimensional array mixed of associative and numeric arrays. At [https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php](php.net) you get a lot of useful examples.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. Both comments are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
$var = $result_array['order']['line_items'][0]['catalog_object_id']
```

There should be no confusion on this. You are traversing through an array so you just have to pick the right element under each array.

You should go through this: [Arrays in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: That's what I thought but I couldn't get it to work and I couldn't find a similar example of traversing an array in PHP. The array was a response from an API, it turns out the value I was looking for just wasn't in the response. Your post was helpful in learning this. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear, Keep Learning!